# Accessing SVG inside object with JS in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, object, svg, xlink

I have a test page: http://benfrain.com/playground/svg-test/

On it I have inserted the same SVG a number of ways (img, object, inline, and background image)

I have also implemented the `use` method of re-using defs from within the SVG (only for the `object` insertion method and the 'inline' insertion method).

In the console you will see I am also attempting to access the SVG contents from each insertion method (I know img and background image should not be accessible via script - I'm just proving the point).

However, on any version of Internet Explorer (IE9+) the `object` insertion method <del>fails to load the external CSS</del> (as noted in the comments, IE requires the alternative linking mechanism) referenced from within (via xlink, you would see a 6px wide stroke if it was working) and it is <del>not reachable via JavaScript (works in all the other evergreen browsers)</del> (my mistake).

Can anyone clarify why? I've had a look through the spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-object-element but I must confess some of the technicalities are beyond my comprehension.

**Update:**
Further to Robert's comments below I made some tweaks to the test page above.

Firstly, the object **is** accessible with script (rookie mistake). However, oddities still abound:

If the SVG has a link in this format: `<?xml-stylesheet href="styles.css" type="text/css"?>` then IE11 applies the styles within that stylesheet to the SVG whether it is inserted in the page via img, background-image, inline or object (Safari/Firefox/Chrome only apply the styles if the SVG is inserted inline or via `object`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a w3c testsuite page for external `<use>`: http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/Test/20110816/svg/struct-use-05-b.svg

The [implementation matrix](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/Test/20110816/status/implementation_matrix.html) suggests that IE9 doesn't support external `<use>` I'm not sure why Firefox is listed as failing as I think even at that time it should have passed that particular test.

For the `<object>` issue, you need to run the script in the onload event of the `<object>` tag. I guess you just get lucky with the other UAs as you basically have a race condition.

Presumably IE doesn't support including stylesheets using html syntax. Try [XML syntax](http://w3.org/TR/SVG/styling.html#StylingWithCSS) instead: `<?xml-stylesheet href="mystyle.css" type="text/css"?>`

Allowing images to use external files is a privacy leak which is why Firefox, Chrome and Safari disallow it. If you converted the CSS to a data URL you could use a link element.

Comment: Hi Robert, thanks for that, that answers the question of external use on IE9 (use from the inline SVG obviously fine). Is there equivalent info for later IEs? However, I still can't ascertain why accessing external stylesheet via xlink or accessing the SVG inside an object via script fails too?

Comment: You need to run the script in the onload event of the `<object>` tag. I guess you just get lucky with the other UAs as you basically have a race condition.

Comment: OK, that makes perfect sense (and I should have already thought of that – apologies) so final piece of the puzzle; is the external stylesheet xlink reference from within the object not working for the same reasons that external use isn't working?

Comment: Presumably IE doesn't support including stylesheets using html syntax. Try XML syntax instead: `<?xml-stylesheet href="mystyle.css" type="text/css"?>` per http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/styling.html#StylingWithCSS

Comment: Thanks so much for your assistance Robert. I'll make that change later on and update. Thanks again.

Comment: Adding the stylesheet in that manner produced interesting results (updated original question with further info)